# How can i delete row from table based on ids coming inside a json

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

**EDIT**

I have a json as parameter in a stored procedure let say that is

```
[{"Guid":"some-id-1"},{"Guid":"some-id-2"}]
```

how can i delete rows from the table where guids are matching above ids inside json

i am using sql server and i havent tried about deleting the record because i have no idea about it. i have inserted the data from this type of json before, using select open json query

**EDIT Again :**

```
Delete [TableName]
        FROM OPENJSON(@json) 
        WITH (Guid uniqueidentifier) as jsonCol
        where TableID = jsonCol.Guid
```

this statement worked for me for only 1 Guid and not for the other one.

please help me for deleting data with all guids inside json.

Comment: Please provide more information and check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. What DB are you using? What have you tried already?

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev i am using sql server and i havent tried about deleting the record because i have no idea about it. i have inserted the data from this type of json before, using select open json query

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me that you need to change you WHERE clause operator from "=" to "IN". Here is the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ccf1a7b03a08a54f1c6bde4e3b19fdc8).

```
DECLARE @json AS VARCHAR(100)

CREATE TABLE YourTable (
TableID uniqueidentifier)

INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES 
('5CF7F5C1-457F-4C3F-A1FA-7D601358B447')
, ('FFB50301-17FC-4476-865C-781125A8AE70')
, ('2F99605E-BFBE-44E1-AAF4-5FFD854D76F4')

SELECT * FROM YourTable

SET @json = '[{"Guid":"5CF7F5C1-457F-4C3F-A1FA-7D601358B447"}, 
{"Guid":"FFB50301-17FC-4476-865C-781125A8AE70"}]'

DELETE FROM YourTable
WHERE TableID IN 
(
    SELECT Guid
    FROM openjson(@json)
    WITH (Guid uniqueidentifier) as jsonCol
)

SELECT * FROM YourTable
```

Comment: changing statement from "=" to "IN" did not work, the result is same. Only first one got executed and remaining are not being executed

Comment: My Bad, as i decorated this
[{"Guid":"5CF7F5C1-457F-4C3F-A1FA-7D601358B447"}, 
{"Guid":"FFB50301-17FC-4476-865C-781125A8AE70"}]
inside ' (single quotation) it worked. thanks

Comment: That is good to hear. It seems that actually your syntax with "=" does work too, as well as "IN (jsonCol.Guid)" and "IN" with sub-select which surprised me. Check it out. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=91978724c063c7045660347822a4e7ad

Comment: excactly. only the missing thing was single quotion. anyways thanks for the help man